# Why FlutterDriver doesn't add functionality to fetch Semantic Properties or Widget Properties using DiagnosticsTree data

Tags: flutter, dart, flutterdriver

In our company, we have created after lots of struggle following dart module, which let us get value of any Widget or Widget's Semantics Properties:

## widget_diagnostics_utils.dart

```
// ignore_for_file: avoid_print
class WidgetDiagnosticsUtils {
  WidgetDiagnosticsUtils(this.widgetDiagnostics);
  final Map<String, dynamic>? widgetDiagnostics;

  Map<String, dynamic>? findChildWidgetDiagnosticsWithRuntimeType(String type) {
    if (widgetDiagnostics == null) return null;

    // If self is of type: $type then return self.
    if (widgetDiagnostics?['widgetRuntimeType'] == type) {
      return widgetDiagnostics;
    }

    // If not childrens then return null.
    if (widgetDiagnostics?['children'] == null) return null;

    final nodeChilds = widgetDiagnostics?['children'] as List;
    for (final Map<String, dynamic> child in nodeChilds) {
      final widgetDiagnosticsUtils = WidgetDiagnosticsUtils(child);
      final result = widgetDiagnosticsUtils
          .findChildWidgetDiagnosticsWithRuntimeType(type);
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }

  dynamic findWidgetDiagnosticsPropertyWithKey(
    Map<String, dynamic>? widgetDiagnostics,
    String key,
  ) {
    if (widgetDiagnostics == null) return null;
    if (widgetDiagnostics['properties'] == null) return null;

    // Cast 'properties' to List<Map<String, dynamic>>
    final properties = List<Map<String, dynamic>>.from(
      widgetDiagnostics['properties'] as dynamic,
    );

    for (final Map<String, dynamic> property in properties) {
      if (property['name'] == key) {
        return property['value'];
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

## Example Use (Text):

```
final finder = find.byValueKey('your_parent_widget_key');

// find descendant child text
final descendantRadioWidget = find.descendant(of: ancestor, matching: find.byType('Text'));

final Map<String, dynamic>? widgetDiagnostics = await driver?.getWidgetDiagnostics(descendantRadioWidget, subtreeDepth: 1, timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30));

final utils = WidgetDiagnosticsUtils(widgetDiagnostics!);
final Map<String, dynamic>? childWidgetDiagnostics = utils.findChildWidgetDiagnosticsWithRuntimeType('Text');

const String property = 'value';
final dynamic value = utils.findWidgetDiagnosticsPropertyWithKey(childWidgetDiagnostics, property);
```

## Example Use (Radio):

```
final finder = find.byValueKey('your_radio_widget_key');
final Map<String, dynamic>? widgetDiagnostics = await driver?.getWidgetDiagnostics(finder, subtreeDepth: 1, timeout: const Duration(seconds: 30));

final utils = WidgetDiagnosticsUtils(widgetDiagnostics!);
final Map<String, dynamic>? childWidgetDiagnostics = utils.findChildWidgetDiagnosticsWithRuntimeType('Semantics');

const String property = 'checked';
final dynamic value = utils.findWidgetDiagnosticsPropertyWithKey(childWidgetDiagnostics, property);
```

We have struggled a lot and it seems its very easy and FlutterDriver should add its support for everyone to use.